# Meteor: segmentation fault 11 while minifying

Tags: javascript, meteor, segmentation-fault, minify

I have a meteor app that recently started stopped deploying b/c of an error that is thrown during the minifying stage of the build process.  The console says:  Segmentation fault 11
... and then it just stops.  The other day I removed a package that I no longer needed, and suddenly the app was able to build and minify successfully.  Then yesterday I updated to Meteor 1.0.5 and the error returned.  What I can do to figure out what's causing this?

Comment: That definitely sounds like a horrible bug within the compile process. Please read about submitting a bug to Meteor: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Contributing-to-Meteor

Comment: After a lot of experimentation, I narrowed it down to my packages.  The minification seems to process files in the order that they are listed in packages.js.  And apparently the order can break the process.  I moved my two largest packages as far away from each other as I could and the problem has stopped for now.  Thanks for the suggestion -- I read the info on that link and I will make a code repro if the problem recurs.